# jQuery: get style attribute and append it to new <div>

Tags: jquery, css, attr

Currently I have an image like this (created by CKEditor):

```
<img src="foo.jpg" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px;" alt="Image text">
```

I want to add a div around this image and extract the text from the alt-tag into a span.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foo img").each(function() {
        $(this).wrap("<div class='imgtxt' />");
        $(this).after($("<span />").text($(this).attr("alt")));
     });
});
```

So far so god! But I also want to get the style attributes from the img and add that to the CSS of the newly created div. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foo img").each(function() {
        $(this).wrap("<div class='imgtxt' />");
        $('.imgtxt').attr('style', $(this).attr('style'));
        $(this).after($("<span />").text($(this).attr("alt")));
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foo img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).wrap("<div id='newdiv" + index + "'" class='imgtxt' />");
        $(this).after($("<span />").text($(this).attr("alt")));
        $("#newdiv" + index).attr('style', $(this).attr('style');
     });
});
```

You're basically creating a unique ID for each DIV and then applying the style each time

Comment: This will apply the style attributes to the relevant DIV, other answers here appear to use classes etc will update ALL other DIVS output from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('div.imgtxt').attr('style', $(this).attr('style'));
```

[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) will grap your `div` you just created. I'd also recommend changing the code to something like this:

```
$("#foo img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.wrap("<div class='imgtxt' />");
    $this.after($("<span />").text($this.attr("alt")));
    // etc.
 });
```

This way you are not looking up/making a jQuery object every time `$(this)` is called!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `$(this).wrap("<div class='imgtxt' />");` with:

```
$(this).wrap("<div class='imgtxt' style=\"" + $(this).attr("style") + "\" />");
```

This takes the style attribute of the image and adds it to the new `div`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var alt   = $(this).attr('alt'),
        style = $(this).attr('style');
    $(this).after("<span>" + alt + "</span>")
           .next('span')
           .andSelf()
           .wrapAll('<div class="imgtxt" style="'+style+'"></div>');
});
```